# Wordpress Ajax Event Calendar

Tags: php, wordpress

Wanting to use: Ajax Event Calendar but the dates are in american format, how do we go about changing this to English??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just going into the code and doing it myself...

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax Event Calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-event-calendar/) supports all formats accepted by WordPress blog date/time settings.

Comment: Correct think the latest version does - the older version didn't.